# Integration issue

Tags: apex, trigger, integration, callout

I am using beeceptor to learn the integration. The scenario is here.
I am creating a case and on this case, account id and description field should auto populate when I run the class via anonymous window. My code is written.

If I remove the where clause from the SOQL it populates one of the account. But I want to populate the Today's created Account. My remote site setting is correct.

I checked the timezone as well.

public class IntegrationPractice {

```
public void caseCreation()
{
 List<Account> lacc= new List<Account>();
            
    lacc=[select id, Name from Account where CreatedDate =: System.today()];
    System.debug(lacc);
    String str = Json.serialize(lacc);
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://hakim.free.beeceptor.com');
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setBody(str);
    req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
   HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);
    System.debug('result '+resp.getBody());
    System.debug('result '+resp.getStatusCode());
    
    Case c = new Case();
        for(Account a:lacc)
        {
            System.debug(a);
            if(resp.getStatusCode()==200)
            {
        
        c.AccountId=a.id;
        c.Description='Updated through API';
         
        } 
        } insert c;
    System.debug(c);
    
}
```

}

*************** Anonymous window code************
IntegrationPractice obj = new IntegrationPractice();
obj.caseCreation();

Comment: I got the answer. I myself changed the SOQL Query. I used Today insetead of System.Today(). It may help to others.

Comment: You can answer your own questions. In fact, we encourage it. Adding an answer will be the way to help future visitors find the answer.